# Flashing Uboot Image to SD Card

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, u-boot

I am trying to flash the uBoot image of MIPS based processor however I dont see anything written to the SD card.

I determined the mount location of the SD card using the following command

```
lsblk
```

I then ran the following command to flash the uBoot image to the sde mount partition as determined from the above command.

```
dd if=uImage of=/dev/sde conv=notrunc bs=1024 seek=4096
```

The terminal tells me that 1.8mb of data is written, but I dont see any data in the SD card. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you looking to see the data?

Comment: I opened up the SD and it was empty. Does it sounds silly ?

Comment: If I am adding contents to the usb such as bootable Ubuntu, I can always open up the files stored in usb or sd